# How to use each element of Arraylist as a column value in SQL statement (iterate the Arraylist for each element)?

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, prepared-statement

I collected the distinct Item value from the table in a ArrayList. Now I want to iterate each value of ArrayList as a column value.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt =conn.preparedStatement("select distinct(A.ID) from Products A,Products B where A.ID=B.ID and A.Item in (?)");
```

The above must comes under the loop and each element in ArrayList is used as the column value for each iteration.

Comment: Can you be little more clear  - You fetched distinct values from DB (using the queries you mentioned) in an ArrayList. Correct? Now you want each element in the array to be used in some other query?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @SandeepJindal why did you reduce my point?

Comment: @SrividhyaShama I did not. I believe comments more meaningful than downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `?` parameter marker for each value, so your code would be something like this.

```
Connection conn = /*connection provided elsewhere*/;
List<String> items = /*item values provided elsewhere*/;

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("select distinct A.ID" +
            " from Products A" +
            " join Products B on B.ID = A.ID" +
           " where A.Item in (");
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0) sql.append(',');
    sql.append('?');
}
sql.append(')');
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString())) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= items.size(); i++)
        stmt.setString(i, items.get(i));
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("ID");
            // use id here
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 8, using a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) can simplify the code a bit.

Comment: I stored the list in "ArrayList <String[]> Item its showing in compactable error.how can i use this code for string array?

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean. Your code was querying using an `in` clause on the `Item` column. Now you're saying you have a List of Arrays? How does that even begin to fit together?